# Stopping jQuery animation loop

Tags: jquery

I have the following animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtqcj/2/

```
jQuery("#fp-small-feature-1").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(".bar").animate({width: "264px"},500);
}); 

jQuery("#fp-small-feature-1").mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(".bar").animate({width: "0px"},800);
});
```

How do I stop the animation from queuing up the effect if you mouse off and over a number of times in quick succession.

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113568/jquery-stop-repeating-animation-on-multiple-rollovers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#fp-small-feature-1").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(".bar").stop().animate({width: "264px"},500);
}); 

jQuery("#fp-small-feature-1").mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(".bar").stop().animate({width: "0px"},800);
}); 

});​
```

Comment: Damn it! beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: Someone answered a question with the same problem a couple of days ago... you both loose ;)

Comment: @Yorgo  Thats what she said :) sorry I had to. +1