# How to stop looping slide in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function where I hover over a content box and a div with class name bottomdata slides down from the top. This function works great, except when you scroll over the box multiple times, the animation runs in a loop. I want to animation to run once, then stop until it is hovered again after the first animation is done looping.

```
    $(".databox").on('mouseenter', '.box', function() {
        $(this).find('.topdata').slideUp(400);
        $(this).find('.bottomdata').slideDown(350);
    }).on('mouseleave', '.box', function() {
        $(this).find('.bottomdata').slideUp();
        $(this).find('.topdata').slideDown();           
    });
```

So I tried to use stop(); I also tried to use finish(). I even tried to use clearQueue(). I just can't seem to figure it out. All help is greatly appreciated.

I have included a sample on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cx1kygc/

Comment: It's not looping on Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Hover over it multiple times and my browsers are Chrome/Firefox on  Windows. I do not believe this is a browser issue.

Comment: Each time I hover, "bottomdata" slides up to cover "topdata". When I exit the box, "bottomdata" goes back down and "topdata" remains at the top. This happens on each hover. What were you wanting to happen?

Comment: @JonathanM, if you flick in and out 9 times, the animation happens 9 times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Stop repeating animation on multiple rollovers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113568/jquery-stop-repeating-animation-on-multiple-rollovers)

Comment: Oh, so you're wanting the first hover to have animation, but none of the other hovers, right? When exiting the box, should "bottomdata" stay at the top, covering "topdata", or should it slide back down as it is now?

Comment: @JonathanM If you move the mouse over the boxes quickly multiple times, it creates a wave effect, since it runs each iteration of hovering one after another in a que. I only want the animation to run once, then once the animation is finished, you may hover over it again.

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277084/stopping-jquery-animation-loop?lq=1

Comment: @JonathanM It should slide back down, and topdata should be showing.

Comment: @isherwood I have tried those and they do not work for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.databox').on('mouseenter', '.box', function() {
    var that = $(this);

    that.find('.topdata').stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
    that.find('.bottomdata').stop(true, true).slideDown(350);
}).on('mouseleave', '.box', function() {
    var that = $(this);

    that.find('.topdata').stop(true, true).slideDown();
    that.find('.bottomdata').stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

<kbd>[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)</kbd>
<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4cx1kygc/11/)</kbd>

Comment: Ah I see, I did not try putting the stop function on each animation. I mainly tried stopping it after the mouseleave, or just the on enter. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The difference is that this solution yes, uses `stop()`, but uses the two parameters, first one to clear the queue and the second one to force the current animation to end abruptly to it's finish point.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I read your comment and assumed that you meant on the first element only, Not all of them. While I do appreciate your help with my troubles, your attitude is only detrimental, nothing constructive can come from that. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie There was Multiple people talking at once, I am not Super-Man. I can only respond to so many at once, and saw your point as something I already tried. I am not bashing you, only stating what happened while I was reading and trying examples. I really do appreciate your input.

Comment: @silentw, I think I'm maybe missing something. How did the behavior change?

Comment: @JonathanM When I move my mouse over the boxes multiple times, it stops the que from running, instead of displaying the animations in what looks like a wave.