# jQuery hover in and out fade transition when changing image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have coded the following which changes the image source and does some attempt of a nice fadeout and fadein when changing the image source but it is not perfect and trying to make it smooth.

The issues I'm facing are:

1. The fading between image changes are messy, should fadeout, change image and fade new one back in but at the moment it seems not the case
2. If you hover in and out a few times it keeps repeating the hover in / out functions; can this only happen once?

Note the first image has active status so no hover required, so please hover the other images to see what I mean.

```js
var $profile = $(".influencers-block-profiles");
var $profileLink = $profile.find("a");
var $activeProfile = $profileLink.hasClass("active");
var imageHoverName = "-hover.jpg";
var imageColourName = "-colour.jpg";

$($profile).find("img").hover(function() {
  $activeProfile = $(this).closest("a").hasClass("active");
  if (!$activeProfile) {
    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace(imageColourName, imageHoverName);
    $(this).not('[src=' + src + ']').fadeOut(500, 0).attr('src', src).fadeIn(500);
  }
  return false
}, function() {
  $activeProfile = $(this).closest("a").hasClass("active");
  if (!$activeProfile) {
    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace(imageHoverName, imageColourName);
    $(this).not('[src=' + src + ']').fadeOut(500, 0).attr('src', src).fadeIn(500);
  }
  return false
});
```

```css
.influencers-block-profiles img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="influencers-block-profiles">
  <a href="#" class="active">
    <img src="https://www.hostandname.co.uk/clients/tests/images/test-photo-hover.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.hostandname.co.uk/clients/tests/images/test-photo-colour.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.hostandname.co.uk/clients/tests/images/test-photo-colour.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: yea i know @halfer been travelling on business so not been online for a few weeks so only just checked my stackoverflow account :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example

```js
var $profile = $(".influencers-block-profiles");
var $profileLink = $profile.find("a");
var $activeProfile = $profileLink.hasClass("active");
var imageHoverName = "-hover.jpg";
var imageColourName = "-colour.jpg";
var TRANSITION_DURATION = 500, inTimeout;

$profile.find("img").hover(function() {
  $activeProfile = $(this).closest("a").hasClass("active");
  if (!$activeProfile) {
    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace(imageColourName, imageHoverName);
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout(inTimeout);
    this.style.opacity = 0;
    inTimout = setTimeout(function(){
      self.src = src;
      self.style.opacity = 1
    }, TRANSITION_DURATION )
  }
  return false
}, function() {
  $activeProfile = $(this).closest("a").hasClass("active");
  if (!$activeProfile) {
    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace(imageHoverName, imageColourName);
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout(inTimeout);
    this.style.opacity = 0;
    inTimout = setTimeout(function(){
      self.src = src;
      self.style.opacity = 1
    }, TRANSITION_DURATION )
  }
  return false
});
```

```css
.influencers-block-profiles img {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="influencers-block-profiles">
  <a href="#" class="active">
    <img src="https://www.hostandname.co.uk/clients/tests/images/test-photo-hover.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.hostandname.co.uk/clients/tests/images/test-photo-colour.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.hostandname.co.uk/clients/tests/images/test-photo-colour.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking great mate, thanks a lot! however is there anyway to stop the repeating if mouse over and out a few times... if you try quickly it will flicking as its changing based on the amount of hover in and out events? thanks very much for coming back to me and helping btw!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `mouseenter` event as an alternative.

The other "trick" is to use the [`finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) function to stop the currently running animation on `mouseleave`

Herewith the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/n0qaxaq0/67/) as a complete solution

Comment: Thanks mate, that solution could work... however when i hover back out it does not change back?

Comment: Also would that not work on mobile when tapping the image?

Comment: Kind of works, if you stay hovering until the fade-in and fade-out completes and move mouse out it changes back but if hover in and out before new image completes it stays on the hover image? any ideas?

Comment: With the edits, does the desired effects happen on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

For stop repeating you need to use jQuery `stop()`. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113598/9453736

For the animation change image with fade in and our I suggest you do this: use a temporary image, I mean a duplicate image of first image and put that duplicate on top of the image that was there.

Then you change the original image's src to new image, and hide the original image which is not behind the temporary image so far no change is seen.

Then you do two animations. Fade out the temporary image which is on top and fade in the original image which was on back. Then you remove the temporary image.

If you had trouble understanding my idea, or have troubles implementing it, let me know